¿Cuál es el nivel de portabilidad de GAS (GNU Assembler) entre distintos sistemas operativos y arquitecturas que no sean Intel usando GCC?
Estoy investigando la portabilidad del GNU Assembler (GAS) entre diferentes sistemas operativos y arquitecturas que no sean Intel con GCC de por medio. Mi objetivo es comprender las limitaciones y posibilidades al escribir código en ensamblador utilizando GAS en entornos no Intel.
¿Qué sistemas operativos y arquitecturas específicas debería considerar?
¿Existen diferencias significativas en la sintaxis o las instrucciones entre plataformas?

No sé mucho del tema, pero recuerdo que GAS es compatible en todo momento siempre y cuando uses GCC escribiendo la misma función para todas las convenciones.

Creo que portabilidad no es la palabra que estás buscando. El código que escribas en ensamblador no lo vas a poder re-ensamblar para otra plataforma o sistema operativo... Las instrucciones son diferentes y la forma de hacer las llamadas al sistema también.
Si te refieres a utilizar el toolchain de GNU en otras plataformas, entonces la respuesta es que puedes utilizar esas herramientas en cualquier plataforma para la que exista Linux.. ya que lo mas probable es que esa versión de Linux se haya reconocido usando esas herramientas.... Hay una pequeña porción del kernel que está escrita en ensamblador así que Gas es utilizado también para esas plataformas.
Respecto a plataformas: Arm, MIPS, Sparc, Risc-V. Respecto a sistemas operativos... En principio cualquier cosa que disponga de código abierto. Los sistemas cerrados (Windows, MacOS) suelen estar ligados a una/unas plataformas hw especifica...
Salvo honrosas excepciones los sistemas operativos suelen estar escritos en C y solo una pequeña parte en ensamblador necesitarías, en el peor de los casos trabajo extra. Hay excepciones como MenuetOs que está escrito en ensamblador, en ese caso específicamente para fasm.
Si buscas portabilidad no deberías utilizar ensamblador sino C o un lenguaje de más alto nivel. Ensamblador es, por definición dependiente de la plataforma.
Espero que esto te ayude

Respondió mi duda, gracias.
